# Using saturate_cast or not

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This is a simple program to change contrast and brightness of an image. I have noticed that there is a an another program with one simple difference:`saturate_cast` is added to code.
And I don't realize what is the reason of doing this and there is no need to converting to unsigned char or `uchar` both code (with `saturate_cast<uchar>` and to not use this) are outputting the same result. I appreciate if anyone help.

Here it is code :

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "Source.h"


using namespace cv;

double alpha;
int beta;
int main(int, char** argv)
{
    /// Read image given by user
    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat image2 = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());



/// Initialize values
        std::cout << " Basic Linear Transforms " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "* Enter the alpha value [1.0-3.0]: ";std::cin >> alpha;
        std::cout << "* Enter the beta value [0-100]: "; std::cin >> beta;
    for (int x = 0; x < image.rows; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.cols; y++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                {
                    image2.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[c] =

                  saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha*(image.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[c]) + beta);

        }
    }

    /// Create Windows
    namedWindow("Original Image", 1);
    namedWindow("New Image", 1);

    /// Show stuff
    imshow("Original Image", image);
    imshow("New Image", image2);


    /// Wait until user press some key
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `alpha*(image.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[c]) + beta` is no more a `uchar`, and can go outside the range [0, 255]. So, use `saturate_cast` to clamp the resulting value correctly

Comment: what is the reason of going outside ?

Comment: `2.0 * (255 + 4)` is outside

Comment: Thanks a lot. but there is one more problem why are they showing same result? But your expression is correct definitely.

Comment: `Vec3b v1, v2; v1[0] = 257; v2[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(257); ` they are not equal

Comment: I got the point.Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the result of your expression may go outside the valid range for `uchar`, i.e. `[0,255]`, you'd better **always use `saturate_cast`**.

---

In your case, the result of the expression: `alpha*(image.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[c]) + beta` is a double, so it's safer to use `saturate_cast<uchar>` to clamp values correctly.

Also, this improves readability, since it's easy to see that you want a `uchar` out of an expression.

---

Without using `saturate_cast` you may have unexpected values:

```
uchar u1 = 257;  // u1 = 1, why a very bright value is set to almost black?
uchar u2 = saturate_cast<uchar>(257); // u2 = 255, a very bright value is set to white
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inline unsigned char saturate_cast_uchar(double val) {
   val += 0.5; // to round the value
   return unsigned char(val < 0 ? 0 : (val > 0xff ? 0xff : val));
}
```

if val lies between 0 to 255 than this function will return rounded value,
if val lies outside the range [0, 255] than it will return lower or upper boundary value.